# Why I can't insert a new line with mail() function?

Tags: php

I am trying to send few emails and ofcourse I need to breake some lines and put some spaces.
This is how I'm trying to do it, without luck:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dataArray); $i++) {
    $to = $dataArray[$i]['email'];
    $subject = 'New member message';
    $message = "Hello!" . "\r\n" . "Member message: " . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . $dataArray[$i]['message'] . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . "This is an automated message, please do not respond to it!";

    $headers = 'From: info@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: info@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n" .
           'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
           'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

But the result leads to a single line text, including the `\r\n` in it as text - it is not inserting a new line.

How can I insert a new line? Why `\r\n` is not working?

I know that I'm missing a really, really small part here, but as a php beginner, I'm not able to spot it.

Comment: Try: `PHP_EOL` does that works for you ? (e.g. `'From: info@domain.com' . PHP_EOL .`)

Comment: you are sending HTML, so may be should add a <br> for a new line ...

Comment: *Content-Type: text/html* .. Send html then, *<br>* instead of *\r\n*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Content-type: text/html`, new line is `<br>`
For `Content-type: text/plain`, new line is `\r\n`

Comment: I knew that I'm missing a small part! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Try <br> tag before /r/n. hope it will work.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a simple 
`<br />` 
for a new line, the 
`\r\n`
is just for the  header

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dataArray); $i++) {
$to = $dataArray[$i]['email'];
$subject  = 'Testing sendmail.exe';
$message = "Hello!" . "\r\n" . "Member message: " . "\r\n" . "\r\n" .         $dataArray[$i]['message'] . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . "This is an automated message, please do not respond to it!";
$headers  = 'From: info@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: info@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
        'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
 echo 'mail send';
}
else
{
 echo 'mail fail';
 }
}
```

Change content type of header to 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'